# Done / How to make a space printer in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var arg = 5
var string = ' '
for (let i = 0; i < arg; i++) {
  console.log('"' + string + '"')
}
```

I expected the output is:

```
"     " \\ There are 5 spaces between the ""
```

But the output is:

```
" "
" "
" "
" "
" "
```

I am a newbie in javascript. Hope you will help me

Comment: You need to add space in a variable then `console.log()` at the finish of `for loop`

Comment: or `console.log(string.repeat(arg))`

Answer (score 2):

you can use method string.padEnd that fill string with blank space until parameter pass to the method

```js
var arg = 5;
var string = ' ';
string = string.padEnd(arg)
console.log('"' + string + '"');
```

reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to console.log on the same line. You can do something like this

```
var arg = 5
var string = ' '
var final_string = ''
for (let i = 0; i < arg; i++)
  final_string = final_string + string
}
console.log('"' + final_string + '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use  &nbsp; or \xa0 for printing spaces

```
var arg = 5
var string = '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0';
for (let i = 0; i < arg; i++) {
  console.log('"' + string + '"')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One would be to do it via a loop. That way you can stay flexible. For loop has already been mentioned. here with a foreach loop.

```js
let string = '';
[...Array(5).keys()].forEach(e => string += ' ');
console.log('"' + string + '"');
```